# What is the best way to store Danish letters in a SQL Server database?

Tags: php, sql-server, collation, letters

I work on a big website on a Linux server (PHP) and with a SQL Server database. 
The SQL Server database uses collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

I have a table (let us call it `table1`) that stores a lot of addresses who are selected from nominatim via a PHP script (script1) and stored in table1. It seems like the format of the addresses is HTML. The Danish letters (æøå) look fine on the website when selected from `table1`.

However I have made a PHP script (script2) that selects these addresses and dump them into another table (`table2`) on the same MS SQL Server (still collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`). But the Danish letters look weird on the website when selected from `table2`. When script1 gets addresses from nominatim it is in JSON format, which is afterwards decoded.

```
$addressdetails = json_decode ( $addressdetails, true );
```

No other encodes or decoding is made here.

The following may also be a help. When I run `phpinfo()` I can see that the server has these settings:

```
PHP version 5.3.3
content type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

What is the best way to handle letters in PHP and SQL Server, so Danish and other special letters are shown the correct way on any platform?

Comment: If you are stuck with a Latin1 database character set, use HTML entities?

Comment: Ah, the problem might be that the PHP `json_` functions require UTF-8, so either you'll need to convert between charsets, or avoid these functions.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like table1 has the address data in an [NVARCHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186939.aspx) typed column whereas table2 has the address data in an [VARCHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms176089.aspx) typed column. NVARCHAR will happily handle æøå but VARCHAR with SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation will not.

If both tables *are* using NVARCHAR to store the data then check that it's not getting converted to VARCHAR at any point between table1 and table2, for example, a VARCHAR stored procedure parameter .

Comment: Given that the O.P. only says that "the Danish letters look weird" and not specifically are coming through as "?", it is not certain that the issue is a `VARCHAR` in the mix. It _could_ have something to do with SQL Server using UTF-16 Little Endian and PHP using UTF-8. Mostly likely it is a `VARCHAR` issue, we just can't rule out something else without more info from the O.P. Still, +1 since everything here is accurate.